# Postfix thinks IP is in blacklist, but is not actually listed in blacklist

Tags: postfix, blacklist, rbl

Got a bit of a weird problem here with Postfix.

Been getting a whole bunch of notices where fail2ban has banned 69.164.196.21 (ryujin.darkdna.net) for failures against Postfix.

Here is a relevant snippet from Postfix's log:

```
Jan 13 17:56:26 postfix/smtpd[14563]: connect from ryujin.darkdna.net[69.164.196.21]
Jan 13 17:56:26 postfix/smtpd[14563]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from ryujin.darkdna.net[69.164.196.21]: 554 5.7.1 Service unavailable; Client host [69.164.196.21] blocked using b.barracudanetworks.org; from=<discuss-owner@lists.opennicproject.org> to=<******> proto=ESMTP helo=<ryujin.darkdna.net>
Jan 13 17:56:27 postfix/smtpd[14563]: disconnect from ryujin.darkdna.net[69.164.196.21]
```

This happens about 4-5 times per day, depending on how much mail gets sent from that maillist.

Now, I get and see that Postfix blocks it as a result of a match against the b.barracudanetworks.org blacklist.

What I don't get is why. As far as I can see from two blacklist checkers (mxtoolbox.org and anti-abuse.org) neither the IP 69.164.196.21 nor the hostname ryujin.darkdna.net is actually listed. (For what it's worth, the host/IP in question seems to be one of Linode's).

This isn't the only host it's blocked. Postfix has apparently been doing this for a while now, blocking hosts it thinks is in the barracudanetworks blacklist when they aren't.

I can access their blacklist just fine from my computers, after following their [testing instructions](http://www.barracudacentral.org/rbl/how-to-use).

I'm stumped, and would appreciate some help or pointers on where to look!

Comment: Hoe does your main.cf look like? especially smtpd_relay_restrictions =

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've mistyped the domain name. It should be `b.barracudacentral.org`, but you entered `b.barracudanetworks.org`. Correct this in your Postfix `main.cf` file.

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
        ...
        reject_rbl_client b.barracudacentral.org,
```